# Javascript arrays builder with multiple sting keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Is there any great idea there that can help me solve my problem regarding the javascript multidimensional arrays builder?

The things that I really want to do is that... i.e I have a form field with name '`fields.0.fld.0.first_name`', that field name needs to transform into javascript array format. The 0 here means as identifier, it classify that the 'fields' word in that field name must / expected to be started as '`new Array()`' because that'll handle multiple sub elements without specific index. And some other strings (a non-integer) that'll only be expected as '`Object`' type of js array or simply as '{}' (that's the last part of the field name the '`first_name`', that will be formatted like '`{first_name: value}`').

Now, since the purpose is to get the fields in the form, I'm looking for a function that will auto generate a constructed json format of those fields with value of course :-). The sample json format output must be...

```
{"fields" : [
        {
            "_id" : "", 
            "type" : "text", 
            "name" : "test1", 
            "id" : "", 
            "class" : "", 
            "conClass" : "s12", 
            "label" : "", 
            "required" : false, 
            "deleted" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "", 
            "type" : "group", 
            "gStart" : "", 
            "gEnd" : "", 
            "flds" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "", 
                    "type" : "text", 
                    "name" : "test2", 
                    "id" : "", 
                    "class" : "", 
                    "conClass" : "s12", 
                    "label" : "", 
                    "required" : false, 
                    "deleted" : false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting us to write code for you ? You should show us what you tried, what it does and what you expected so that we can *help* you.

Comment: I already posted it. I don't have idea how to comply that that's why I'm posting here. If you'll refer to what I've tried then you will probably get a wrong answer also. I'm referring to those people who has brilliant idea or has the same issue that was already resolved.

Comment: Sorry but I think you misunderstood the goal of StackOverflow. We are here to help you regarding code you have written, sorry.

Comment: ok, but for sure there's a lot of guys out there who has an idea and maybe willing to share. just ignore if you don't like to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it. Based on the naming structure and required logic, I've discovered that the js eval is very useful. Now I can create multi-demensional array of js using the function below.

```
function _arr_definer(items, _arr_handler, _curr, _val)  
    {
        var _tmp_indexes = "";
        if(_curr > 0){
            for(var _i = 0; _i < _curr; _i++){
                if(Number(items[_i]) >= 0)
                    _tmp_indexes += "[" + items[_i] + "]";
                else
                    _tmp_indexes += "['" + items[_i] + "']";
            }

            if(typeof eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + "['" + items[_curr] + "']") == 'undefined'){
                if(Number(items[_curr]) >= 0){
                    if(typeof items[_curr + 1] != 'undefined'){
                        if(Number(items[_curr + 1]) >= 0){
                            var _temp_sub = [];
                            if(typeof eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes) != 'undefined')
                                eval("_temp_sub = _arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes);
                            _temp_sub[items[_curr]] = [];
                            eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + " = _temp_sub;");   
                        }else{
                            var _temp_sub = [];
                            if(typeof eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes) != 'undefined')
                                eval("_temp_sub = _arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes);

                            _temp_sub[items[_curr]] = {};
                            eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + " = _temp_sub;");   
                        }
                    }else{ //assign value
                        eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + "['"+ items[_curr] +"'] = _val;");
                    }
                }else{
                    if(typeof items[_curr + 1] != 'undefined'){
                        if(Number(items[_curr + 1]) >= 0){
                            var _temp_sub = {};
                            if(typeof eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes) != 'undefined')
                                eval("_temp_sub = _arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes);
                            _temp_sub[items[_curr]] = [];
                            eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + " = _temp_sub;");   
                        }else{
                            var _temp_sub = {};
                            if(typeof eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes) != 'undefined')
                                eval("_temp_sub = _arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes);
                            _temp_sub[items[_curr]] = {};
                            eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + " = _temp_sub;");   
                        }
                    }else{ //assign the value
                        eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + "['"+ items[_curr] +"'] = _val;");
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(typeof eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + "['"+ items[_curr] +"']") == 'undefined'){
                if(typeof items[_curr + 1] != 'undefined'){
                    if(Number(items[_curr + 1]) >= 0){
                        eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + "['"+ items[_curr] +"'] = [];");
                    }else{
                        eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + "['"+ items[_curr] +"'] = {};");
                    }
                }else{ //assign the value
                    eval("_arr_handler" + _tmp_indexes + "['"+ items[_curr] +"'] = _val;");
                }
            }
        }

        if(typeof items[_curr + 1] != 'undefined'){
            _arr_definer(items, _arr_handler, _curr + 1, _val);
        }
    }
```

And for using it just follow the declaration below.

```
var _arr_handler = {};

    var _items = "fields.0.flds.0.conClass".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0, 'This is a testing content');

    var _items = "fields.0.flds.0.first_name".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0);

    var _items = "fields.0.flds.0.subnames.0.nice".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0);


    var _items = "other.cool.cool1.cooler.test".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0);

    var _items = "other.cool.cool1.othersubs.0".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0, true);

    var _items = "other.cool.cool1.othersubs.1".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0, false);

    var _items = "more_field_1".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0);

    var _items = "more_field_2".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0);

    var _items = "more_field_3".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0);

    var _items = "more_field_4.subs.0.item_1".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0);

    var _items = "more_field_4.subs.0.item_2".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0);

    var _items = "more_field_4.subs.0.item_3".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0);

    var _items = "more_field_4.subs.0.item_4".split('.');
    _arr_definer(_items, _arr_handler, 0);

    console.log(_arr_handler);
```

The purpose of this is to... save the MongoDB document in one trigger only including the sub->sub->sub->sub elements. :-)

Cheers